# what's the best way to integrate dataTables with cakePhp using the MVC approach

Tags: php, cakephp, datatables

I've done up a bit of code in which I attempt to integrate data tables (http://datatables.net/) with cakePHP.

It's up and running with my own app, but I want to make it more generic, so it can be used by anyone across any cakePhp application, and most importantly I want it to fit in with cakePHP conventions.

So at the moment this is what I have...

A cakePHP helper called `dataTables`, which takes the following arguments: `$modelName`, `$fields`, `$headers`.

- `$modelName` is the name of the model whose data will be populating the table.
- `$fields` is an array of fields we want to show in the table (all fields must be prepended with "ModelName." which means we can show associated model values in the table)
- `$headers` is a list of headers we want to be displayed at the top of the table.

The helper produces an empty html table (with the `$headers` as headers). The table is then populated by datables' javascript (you might have to read up on [this](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html) if you're not familiar with dataTables server-side processing).

The Javascript retrieves the table data from the `dataTable()` action of the controller whose model we want to get at. The javascript will also send the model name (which we sent to the helper), and the fields. The controller then prints out the JSON data (through a blank view)

My two main questions are:

1. It doesn't seem right to place the dataTable action in a controller. A) because it doesn't actually need the controller because it knows what model and fields it needs to load and B) because it's not really a **user** action, its really just a JSON response. So where should it be put?
2. To print the JSON repsonse for my `dataTable()` action, I use a "`blank.ctp`" view and the use `echo jsonencode($output)`. It doesn't seem right to use a view to output JSON data. Usually views are just for the user right?

One way of answering both of these questions is to have a standalone `dataTable.php` file, which will print the relevant JSON data based on the model name and fields it receives.
But this ^^ doesn't seem logical considering the MVC pattern.

The code is a bit messy at the moment (answers to the above should help me tidy it up!) but let me know if need to see.

Hope this makes sense to someone other then myself..

Comment: Combine a Behavior with the Component - actsAs DataTable.Table could expose a model function for the component to call that returns your json as needed.

Comment: I would like to see the code you have developed. I was looking for a solution to implement CakePHP with jQuery Datatbale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about this for a second and a plugin seems to be the best idea.
You can use a Component to load the helper automatically and give you a controller visible hook to set the data for the helper/element that provides the output.

Use a behavior to expose the model function for your json, and then use the component to set the data.

As far as whether or not you should use a view or not - here is the section from the book on json views.

> The _serialize key is a special view variable that indicates which
>   other view variable(s) should be serialized when using a data view.
>   This lets you skip defining view files for your controller actions if
>   you don’t need to do any custom formatting before your data is
>   converted into json/xml.
>
> If you need to do any formatting or manipulation of your view
>   variables before generating the response, you should use view files.
>   The value of _serialize can be either a string or an array of view
>   variables to serialize:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key

Comment: What do you mean by a "controller visible hook"?

Comment: Simply a function in the Component that is used to set the data you need. The Component functions can be called directly from the Controller - meaning if you use the Component in your AppController you have access to the function to set/manipulate your json data available in every sub classed Controller you might need to use it in.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a CakePHP Componenent that handles this https://github.com/cnizzdotcom/cakephp-datatable